# Access observable data from upper foreach with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Im trying to access information from two different arrays within my viewModel with two foreach loops, but the items are not nested within each other

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: runnr">
    <tr>
        ......
        <!--ko foreach: $root.options -->
        <td data-bind="visible: value"><span data-bind="text: runnr[prop] "></span></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

I want 'visible' to be set to the options value property, but the span text I want set to a property from runnr based on the prop from options.

```
options = ko.observableArray([
  { name: "PP", value: pp, prop: 'Post' },
  { name: "Weight", value: weight, prop: 'Weight' },
  { name: "Price", value: price, prop: "Price" }]);

runnr = ko.observableArray([
    {Post:1, Weight:125, Price:12000},
    {Post:2, Weight:124, Price:15000}
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `$parent[prop]` to access the `runnr` that you are looping over.

Simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/y3R43/

Comment: huh, I know I tried that.. but its working now.. I must have had something else out of place before. Thanks